# Need help returning a string with multiple variables in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, function, return

I need to write a function that returns a string for a project I'm doing.  I currently have 5 variables in this function.  I've tried figuring out how to construct the string inside the return statement with the variables included, but when I print the function out I always end up with quotes around the strings and I can't put a new line between the different strings.

I need it to print the what the total miles are on one line, net miles on the next, etc...  Whenever I add a new line in the string, it just prints the \n character out instead.

I just can't seem to figure out how to do it.  I cannot have print statements inside the function, it all has to be printed out from the return value.  The logic works fine but I can't get past this for the life of me.

```
def report_stats(total_cost,gallons_used):
    global total_distance
    global net_miles
    var1 = "Total Miles Traveled: ", total_distance
    var2 = "Net Miles: ", net_miles
    var3 = "Gallons used: ", gallons_used
    var4 = "Total Cost: ", total_cost
    if total_cost < 25:
        how_much = "Cha Chiiinng!"
    if 25 <= total_cost < 100:
        how_much = "Wallet getting nervous!"
    else:
        how_much = "Ouch!"
    return var1,var2,var3,var4,how_much
print(report_stats(total_cost,gallons_used))
```

Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: can you post all the variables

Comment: I'm getting a `"'total_distance' is not defined"` error. If I correct that, I get `"'net_miles' is not defined"` error. You didn't report any of those; so this is not [mcve].

Comment: My mistake.  Those were global variables and I didn’t include them in my little snippet of code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use string interpolation here. 
in python 3.6+ you can do the following

```
var1 = f"Total Miles Traveled: {total_distance}"
```

so in your return you can do the following..

```
def report_stats(total_cost,gallons_used):
var1 = f"Total Miles Traveled: {gallons_used}"
var2 = f"Total Miles Traveled: {gallons_used}"
var3 = f"Total Miles Traveled: {gallons_used}"
var4 = f"Total Miles Traveled: {gallons_used}"
if total_cost < 25:
    how_much = "Cha Chiiinng!"
if 25 <= total_cost < 100:
    how_much = "Wallet getting nervous!"
else:
    how_much = "Ouch!"
return f"{var1}\n{var2}\n{var3}\n{var4}\n{how_much}"
print(report_stats(10,2))
```

output :

```
Total Miles Traveled: 2
Total Miles Traveled: 2
Total Miles Traveled: 2
Total Miles Traveled: 2
Ouch!
```

Answer (score 0):

Your vars should probably be strings (now they are tuples). Change that and use Python's triple quotes, as shown below:

```
def report_stats(total_cost,gallons_used):
    global total_distance
    global net_miles
    var1 = "Total Miles Traveled: " + str(total_distance)
    var2 = "Net Miles: " + str(net_miles)
    var3 = "Gallons used: " + str(gallons_used)
    var4 = "Total Cost: " +  str(total_cost)
    if total_cost < 25:
        how_much = "Cha Chiiinng!"
    if 25 <= total_cost < 100:
        how_much = "Wallet getting nervous!"
    else:
        how_much = "Ouch!"
    return """{}
{}
{}
{}
{}""".format(var1, var2, var3, var4, how_much)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a concept called unpacking in Python. Something like this:

```
def report_stats(total_cost,gallons_used):
    global total_distance
    global net_miles
    var1 = "Total Miles Traveled: ", total_distance
    var2 = "Net Miles: ", net_miles
    var3 = "Gallons used: ", gallons_used
    var4 = "Total Cost: ", total_cost
    if total_cost < 25:
        how_much = "Cha Chiiinng!"
    if 25 <= total_cost < 100:
        how_much = "Wallet getting nervous!"
    else:
        how_much = "Ouch!"
    return var1,var2,var3,var4,how_much
var1,var2,var3,var4,how_much = report_stats(total_cost,gallons_used)
print(var1 + '\n' + var2 + '\n' + var3 + '\n' + var4 + '\n' + how_much')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension:

```
[print(x) for x in report_stats(total_cost,gallons_used)]
```